# AppFabric simulate cache failure

Tags: appfabric, appfabric-cache

Is there a way to simulate a Cache failure in AppFabric?

I want to hit the `AddFailureNotificationCallback` delegate in my code, for testing purposes.

Thanks

Comment: You could try flooding the cache with requests for a large object